# MapKit pin not displaying leftCalloutAccessoryView

Tags: ios, objective-c, mapkit, mkannotationview

I am following the iOS 5 version of Paul Hegarty's lecture on ios app developing, and I am working on assignment 5.

So basically I need to display a bunch of images on a map with the data provided from Flickr.

I got the pins working and displaying title and subtitles, however, when I try to put a `UIImageView` as the `leftCalloutAccessoryView`, it is not working.

So I set map view controller as the delegate of its mapView in `viewDidLoad` and it conforms to the `MKMapViewDelegate` protocol.

And I implemented the following two methods:

```
- (MKAnnotationView *)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView viewForAnnotation:(id<MKAnnotation>)annotation {
    MKAnnotationView *aView = [mapView dequeueReusableAnnotationViewWithIdentifier:@"MapVC"];
    if (!aView) {
        aView = [[MKPinAnnotationView alloc] initWithAnnotation:annotation reuseIdentifier:@"MapVC"];
        aView.canShowCallout = YES;
        aView.leftCalloutAccessoryView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 30, 30)];
    }
    aView.annotation = annotation;
    [(UIImageView *)aView.leftCalloutAccessoryView setImage:nil];
    return aView;
}
```

and

```
- (void)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView didSelectAnnotationView:(MKAnnotationView *)view {
    UIImage *image = [self.delegate mapViewController:self imageForAnnotation:view.annotation];
    [(UIImageView *)view.leftCalloutAccessoryView setImage:image];
}
```

However, when I click on a pin, it only shows title and subtitle. I am not sure what is going on since at this step basically all of my code are similar to his example in the video and I'm not sure what I am missing.

Thanks for your help!

---------------------------------Update:----------------------------------

I figured out my problem.

The problem is that I was `segue`ing into the mapViewController, and I was adding the annotations in `prepareForSegue`, however, the `mapView` is an `IBOutlet` for the controller and it is not set yet in `prepareForSegue`, so basically I need to update my `mapView` again with the annotations passed to the controller in `viewDidLoad`, this indeed solved the problem.

Hopefully this will help anyone out there with similar problem!

Comment: Try to log the image variable in the didSelectAnnotationView to see if it is correct.

Comment: @verbumdei it does show the memory address of the image. So I think I am getting the image correctly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem myself, see the ***update*** part in question.